# Does water orm in sails support union?

Tags: sails.js

I'm writing some api with sails framework. I have one api that need to get data from two table so I would want to use a sql query like this:

```
select * from table1 union select * from table2
```

I know that for that query I can use Model.query. It would be something like this:

```
    Model.query("select * from table1 union select * from table2"
              ).exec(function(err, data){
        //some process
    });
```

But for that data that return to me in some json field would be string instead of json and I hate that. So I wonder if I can use that query with water orm in sails? Currently, I'm using MySQL and sails version 0.12.13

Comment: Any response on this?  I'm facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is quite late but I saw this question now. You can create a new connection as follows:

```
ReadOps.js

const mySqlDbRead = {
    'development': 'devMysqlDbRead',
  };

module.exports = {
    connection: mySqlDbRead['development'],
    attributes: {

    },
}
```

You can write the query as follows:

```
 const query = "select * from table1 union select * from table2";
 ReadOps.query(query,  (err, data) => {
    console.log(data);
 }
```